# C# - Hydrate existing object with XML

Tags: c#, xml

I know I can use Linq to map fields from XML to fields in a pre-existing object. Are there any functions in the .NET Framework (or other libraries) that make this less manual.

I would like to write (and have the HydrateFromXml behave a little like AutoMapper does):

```
var myObject = new MyObject(/*ctor args*/);

myObject = myObject.HydrateFromXml(string xml);
```

**Edit:**

Could I use the decorator pattern or a simple wrapper object here? Deserialize directly into a type that is wrapped by an abstraction that permits the fine-grained construction control I need?

Comment: I did someting a bit similar mark teh properties with serialisation attributes. Then write a method that reflects out marked up properties and then dig around in the xml for the content to set them. Saying that assuming there's no cross over between constrcutor args and Hydration, waht about revesing it. Use serialisation to get one then set the constructor arguemnts?

Comment: Might I inquire as to what "hydrate" means in this context?

Comment: @KennethK. I think that is the crux of the problem. I would like the properties on `myObject` to be initialized with the corresponding values in the XML, but doing so means telling the program how to do it. I was looking for something that didn't involve manually mapping fields, but it looks like this is not possible.

Comment: Mapping is unavoidable.Having to write the mapping code for each class is all you can avoid and that has to be through implicit or explicit meta data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to do that:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

object result;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    result= serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

var myObject = result as MyObject;
```

For a situation when you're object instance already exists check this question: [Deserializing properties into a pre-existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341566/deserializing-properties-into-a-pre-existing-object)

Comment: No need for the `as` in the last line - it will only ever be a `MyObject`, so you can just cast.

Comment: This does not appear to answer my question because `result` does not pre-exist the deserialization step. I would like to hydrate a pre-existing object instance.

Comment: So you don't have `MyObject` declaration at all?

Comment: Per my question I have an object instance `myObject`. I would then like to hydrate properties on this object using an XML document. The reason for this is that I would like more control over the construction of the object - I would like to supply a constructor argument when constructing `myObject` - the plain deserialization option doesn't permit this AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick option, you could use AutoMapper. Use the XmlSerializer to deserialize to a new instance and then use AutoMapper to map from the newly created instance to your required instance.